# Why is this </p> out of place in this HTML5 document (rendered by Django)?

Tags: html

The indentation was created by Firefox's source. Both Firefox and HTML validators said that the `</p>` is misplaced. But I can't figure out why.

```
<p>
  <ul class="errorlist">
    <li>This field is required.</li>
  </ul>
  <label for="id_creator">Creator:</label>
  <select onchange="Dajaxice.doors.orders_create_creator_changed(fill_other_fields, {&#39;creator_pk&#39;: this.options[this.selectedIndex].value})" name="creator" id="id_creator">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a user</option>
    <option value="9">Amy the Tenant</option>
    <option value="6">Alex the Tenant</option>
    <option value="3">Bob the Property Manager</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

On a side note, when Django doesn't render the error messages, then the closing `</p`> tag is valid. Here is the code:

```
<p>
  <label for="id_creator">Creator:</label>
  <select onchange="Dajaxice.doors.orders_create_creator_changed(fill_other_fields, {&#39;creator_pk&#39;: this.options[this.selectedIndex].value})" name="creator" id="id_creator">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a user</option>
    <option value="9">Amy the Tenant</option>
    <option value="6">Alex the Tenant</option>
    <option value="3">Bob the Property Manager</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` can't include any block-level elements ([see MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/HTML/Element/p)).

`<ul>` on the other hand is an block level element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/HTML/Element/ul)).

The reason your code might be displayed "correctly" is that most html5 parsers insert a closing `</p>` when they encounter a block level element inside a `<p>`. With this being inserted your actual `</p>` has no accompanying opening `<p>` and in consequence is not valid at that point.

Comment: The reason his code displays correctly is because browsers try very hard to deal with malformed and invalid HTML. That doesn't make it correct or valid.

Comment: @Truth Accoding to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) The insertion of the `</p>` tag is standard conform (we could discuss the cleanness of the code, though). So following this the closing `</p>` without any opening tag can be seen as invalid markup, whereas the rest is standard conform.

Comment: @Sirko: Closing the `</p>` element is always valid (assuming one was opened). It's optional to omit the closing tag if it is followed by one of the following elements:  address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul.

Comment: @Truth I think you didn't get my point. From a parsers perspective the code is perfectly valid until it gets to the `</p>`. This is the first (only?) invalid tag in that code (from the parsers simple point of view). From the developer's point of view the `<ul>` is misplaced here.

Answer (score 1):

an `<ul />` is block level so it can't be held inside a `<p />`